# td:first-child doesnt work for dynamically generated td

Tags: css

I am not able to get td:first-child to work for dynamically created `<td>` in statically created table.
I have the following static mark up

```
    <table class="tblgenInfo">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Controls.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (Model.Controls[i].HtmlAttributes["section"].ToString() != "0")
            {
                continue;
            }

            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Controls[i].Type)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Controls[i].ID)
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Controls[i])


             </tr>
          }
        </table>
```

In the above code, @EditorFor(x => x.Control[i]) creates controls inside `<td>` dynamically.
I have the following CSS which works if `<td>`s are created statically but doesnt work for dynamically created ones.Please help.

```
    .tblgenInfo  tr  td:first-child{
     width: 28%;
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the dynamically generated ones appending to `tr` as first childs?

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML ?

Comment: If other elements are generated inside the `tr` before the `td` you'll need to use `td:first-of-type`

Comment: @singe31 : Thanks! That did work.I am new to this forum, so how do I set your answer/comment as the accepted one.I had some elements generated before the first '<td>' as is obvious from the code above (@HiddenFor)

Comment: I didn't provide any solution

Comment: @Danield: Thanks 'td:first-of-type' worked for me

Comment: @single31: Oops! That was intended for Danield.Thanks anyway! Looks like I am nervous being a first timer.

Comment: @Jiny - I just submitted an answer. You can accept it by checking the green check mark next to the answer

Comment: @Jiny - you marked the wrong answer as correct - `first-child` doesn't work as you yourself mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since other elements are generated inside the tr before the td - the `first-child` selector won't work.

In your case, you need to use the `first-of-type` selector.

So your code becomes:

```
.tblgenInfo  tr  td:first-of-type { 
   width: 28%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put your css in the footer so that the styling is called after the page has loaded?

```
<footer>

<p>your footer words</p>

<style>
   .tblgenInfo  tr  td:first-child { width: 28%; }
 </style>

</footer>
```